# When are multiplicities of two weights equal in simple highest weight modules

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple (or simple) Lie algebra over $\mathbb{C}$. Take a Cartan subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\Phi$ be the root system of $\mathfrak{g}$ w.r.t. $\mathfrak{h}$, and $\Delta\subset\Phi$ be a set consisting of simple roots. Let $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$ be a integral dominant weight, i.e. $<\lambda,\alpha>$ are nonnegative integers for any simple root $\alpha\in\Delta$.

We know there is an unique irreducible highest weight module $L(\lambda)$ with highest wight $\lambda$.

A well-known result is:

> $L(\lambda)$ is finite dimensional, and $$
>  \operatorname{dim}L(\lambda)_\mu=\operatorname{dim}L(\lambda)_{w(\mu)},\  \ \forall w\in W, \mu\in \mathfrak{h}^*.$$

My question is: for what kind of integral dominant weight $\lambda\in\Lambda_+$, can we say:$$
\operatorname{dim}L(\lambda)_\mu=\operatorname{dim}L(\lambda)_{\nu}\qquad \operatorname{iff}\qquad  \mu\in W.\nu
$$

I try to use Kostant formulas but it seems to be hard to get some useful information. I post that formula below:

> $$\operatorname{dim}\ L(\lambda)_\mu=\sum_{w\in W}(-1)^{l(w)}p(\mu+\rho-w(\lambda+\rho))$$where $p=\operatorname{ch}M(0)$, the formal character of Verma module $M(0)$, and $\rho$ is one half of the sum of all positive roots.

Comment: It is true for the trivial representation, and true for the adjoint representations as long as the rank is 2 or more, and the root system is simply-laced and indecomposable (there is only one length of root, and all roots are in the same $W$-orbit). It may be true for other representations, but it seems like a difficult condition to work with in general, and I think it will not be true for “most” highest weights.

Comment: Thank you!! Yse, I have noticed that. The $W$-orbit of $\Phi$ is clear: two roots are in the same orbit iff they have same square length. and I agree with you that it's not true for "most" weights.

Comment: For example, the weights of $V(\lambda)$ lie in the convex hull of $W\cdot \lambda$. Along the boundary of this convex hull, every integral weight has a weight space of dimension 1. But most are in separate $W-orbits$, unless $\lambda$ is very small.

Comment: @Joppy That's interesting! But I cannot see clearly why all integral weights in the boundary of the convex hull of $W\lambda$ must have multiplicity $1$. Could you give me some more explanation? If it is not easy to say, would you mind offering some references about that？

Comment: For each $i$, the weight spaces $\lambda, \lambda - \alpha_i, \ldots, s_i(\lambda)$ are at least one-dimensional, with $V(\lambda)_\lambda$ and $V(\lambda)_{s_i(\lambda)}$ being exactly one-dimensional. If any of the intermediate spaces were more than one dimensional, there would be some nonzero vector $v$ in that space such that $e_i(v) = 0$, and since we are on the boundary of the convex hull, $e_j(v) = 0$ for all $j \neq i$ as well. Hence $v$ would be a different highest-weight vector in $V(\lambda)$.

Comment: @joppy I got your idea. But how about the integral weights belonging to the boundary which is not belongs to $W(A)$, where $A:=\{\lambda-i\alpha\ |\ i\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq0},\ \alpha\in\Delta\}$?

Comment: Up to now, I have known that only finitely many dominant weights satisfy my condition. They are: $\sum_{i\in I}\omega_i$, where $I$ is any subset of $\{1,\ldots l\}$, and $\omega_1,\ldots,\omega_l$ are all fundamental weights. So the question comes to analyse these finitely many cases. Please write comments or answers if you have a better answer~!